# How to add/update product from magento 1 to magento 2 website

Tags: magento-1.9, product, api, catalog

**Website 1 - www.domain1.com (Magento 1)**

**Website 2  www.domain2.com(Magento 2)**

If any product is uploaded on Magento 2 I want to also upload on Magento 1

it's possible?

Comment: Why not using one magento with two websites?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt Client needs different payment menthod, different shipping method and different store and currency.

Comment: no problem. this can be achieved with two websites.

Comment: do you have any article or tutorial link ?

Comment: https://www.google.de/webhp?q=magento+store+view+tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following event

```
catalog_product_save_commit_after
```

in that event you can use any API (soap or REST) to create a new product.

Follow this [**tutorial**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.create.html) to create the product using `scop API`

Comment: is there any other default setting or function in magento ?

Comment: as of my knowledge no.